# How to check, whether graphics card suits the application needs?

Tags: c++, gpu, directx-11

I've got an application, which uses DirectX11's specific functions. Is there a way other than trying to create ID3D11Device to determine, whether card supports this version of DirectX?

And second question: how can I determine, how much VRAM does the graphics card have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to check, whether graphics card supports DirectX 11 seems - unfortunatelly - to be simply trying to create a ID3D11Device with specific feature set. I didn't found any easier way.

To verify, how much VRAM does the graphics card have, one may use [GetDesc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb174526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of IDXGIAdapter interface.

Answer (score 0):

[DirectXSetupGetVersion()](http://doc.51windows.net/Directx9_SDK/?url=/directx9_sdk/setup/reference/functions/directxsetupgetversion.htm) seems to to able to detect the currently installed dx version.
While looking for a solution on how to detect the amount of VRAM, I came across [this library](http://www.ozone3d.net/zoomgpu/) which seems to be able to detect a large amount of properties of your video card, it might be worth looking into ;).

Comment: Post on this thread http://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=25706&start=15 tells, that DirectXSetupGetVersion simply checks for an entry in registry and concerns installed DirectX version, not the graphics card capabilities. I'm affraid, I can't use it.

Comment: @spook You said you have an application with dx11 specific functions. If the graphics card is capable of dx11 but it is not installed those functions won't work either.

Comment: In such case, due to lack of required DLLs, the application won't even start :) However, DirectX 11 has a compatibility mode, which allows using DX9 card with DX11 API, but I require both DX11 API *and* its features.